# is it possible to open an activity after scanning a QR code?

Tags: java, android, qr-code, barcode-scanner

Is it possible to open an activity after scanning a QR code?
and How to create QR CODE for an Activity so that When i scan that activity should open
please help me with my project

I Don't know how to create QR code for an activity